# How do I set Screen Tip Style for Excel Ribbon UI using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

How can I set the selected feature using VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office applications keep their settings in Windows registry keys. I'd suggest using the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) utility for locating the exact place.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I downloaded Process Monitor and it's not that easy for the first time! I just found the registry key by searching for 'screentipcheme'. Thanks.